# How do I use my own functions with start: stop: while using the parameters 'ev' and 'ui'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, user-defined-functions

In my draggables, the code at `start:` and `stop:` is getting too big (50-100 lines) that I am starting to have readability issues.

```js
$(".dra").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(ev, ui){
        //...50-100 lines...
    },
    stop: function(ev, ui){
        //...50-100 lines...
    }
});
```

To fix the readability, I want to create two global functions `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` and just insert them like `start: startDrag(ev, ui)`. But I failed managed to make this work:

```js
function startDrag(ev, ui){
    //...50-100 lines...
}

function stopDrag(ev, ui){
    //...50-100 lines...
}

function createDraggables(){
    $(".dra").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        start: startDrag(ev, ui),
        stop: stopDrag(ev, ui)
    });
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: The problem is when you have a line like `start: startDrag(ev, ui)`, you are telling it to execute whatever `startDrag(ev, ui)` returns, rather than the function itself. As people have suggested, removing the arguments like this `start: startDrag` tells it to actually execute the function each time the event is fired.

Comment: You fix this problem by understanding how to use function references in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of function scope, could be just write like this:

```
function createDraggables(){
    $(".dra").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        start: startDrag,
        stop: stopDrag
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing it to:

```
function createDraggables(){
    $(".dra").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        start: startDrag,
        stop: stopDrag
    });
}
```